# Win 10 mouse pointer freezes few seconds when tooltips are shown

Tags: windows-10, mouse

Win 10 mouse pointer freezes few seconds when tool tips are shown in any application, browser or even desktop. Any idea how to fix it..!?

Comment: Can you add a moving GIF with a timer or something to help visualize better what you are experiencing?

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to fully patched your system with Windows Update/Hotfix. It is helpful for resolving some known issues and improving the performance.

Please reference “**Windows 10 update history**” and make sure that your system is up to date:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4018124/windows-10-update-history

Besides, you may try to re-start system in Clean Boot, do not manually start another other process, if problem does not happen, then, try to manually start application/process one by one, to identify if this problem happens to specific application process.

**How to perform a clean boot in Windows**:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows

Also, it is recommend to check/install/update hardware driver, such as display driver, mouse driver and etc. to check the result.

Best Regards,
Eve Wang